Error initializing Airflow webserver version 2.3.1
I'm having an issue with Airflow webserver initializing on Kubernetes:
[2024-07-14 04:01:49 +0000] [17] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2024-07-14 04:02:00,481] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/common/_connection.py:82 SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
[2024-07-14 04:02:03 +0000] [17] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (17)
[2024-07-14 04:02:03 +0000] [17] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2024-07-14 04:02:03 +0000] [23] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py:2576 SAWarning: Multiple rows returned with uselist=False for eagerly-loaded attribute 'Permission.action'
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py:2576 SAWarning: Multiple rows returned with uselist=False for eagerly-loaded attribute 'Permission.resource'
[2024-07-14 04:02:06,566] {init_appbuilder.py:587} ERROR - Multiple rows were found when one or none was required
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/www/extensions/init_appbuilder.py", line 585, in _add_permission
    self.sm.add_permissions_view(baseview.base_permissions, baseview.class_permission_name)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/www/fab_security/manager.py", line 1407, in add_permissions_view
    self.delete_permission(perm.action.name, resource_name)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/www/fab_security/sqla/manager.py", line 527, in delete_permission
    perm = self.get_permission(action_name, resource_name)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/www/fab_security/sqla/manager.py", line 471, in get_permission
    self.get_session.query(self.permission_model)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2760, in one_or_none
    return self._iter().one_or_none()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 1369, in one_or_none
    return self._only_one_row(True, False, False)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 620, in _only_one_row
    raise exc.MultipleResultsFound(
sqlalchemy.exc.MultipleResultsFound: Multiple rows were found when one or none was required

This happened after a migrating to another platform, but loading the postgres dump seemed to work correctly. Database is Postgres. Any ideas on how to debug this?
